# Power app formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, powerapp, formula, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to disable the button, if two text fields are not completed.

I am using formula:

```
If( IsBlank(TextInput7.Text) or IsBlank(TextInput1_4.Text) , Disabled, Edit)
```

This is giving me error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below:

```
If(IsBlank(TextInput7.Text) || IsBlank(TextInput1_4.Text), Disabled, Edit)
```

OR

```
If(Or(IsBlank(TextInput7.Text), IsBlank(TextInput1_4.Text)), Disabled, Edit)
```

Comment: Both options work. :) Thansk ganesh